# Can a contract's internal storage keep increasing forever?

Tags: contract-design, gas, storage, gas-limit

In other words, is there a limit on the amount of storage a contract can hold?

Suppose a field is an Array for instance, and the contract has a method for adding items. Can I keep calling the contract so it adds more and more data?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, a contract has infinite internal storage.

But there are **2 limits to practicality**: **gas costs** and the **block gas limit**.

Gas costs are discussed in:
[Is there anything stopping me from using the ethereum blockchain as data storage?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-there-anything-stopping-me-from-using-the-ethereum-blockchain-as-data-storage)

Furthermore, the block gas limit will limit how much computation, search, iteration, etc can be performed on the data.

Comment: Correction single contract can hold 2^261 bytes (2^256 keys * 32b)

Comment: Oh, yeah I screwed up the math again. Dang.

Comment: See the more detailed explanation here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1040/16

Answer (score 3):

No, contracts' internal storage cannot increment forever. However, it is fairly more than enough for all types of purposes.

The limits for all storage variables together is:

2^256 Keys of 32 bytes = 2^261 bytes .

This is:
115,792,089,237,316,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 of Keys 32 bytes.

That is equal to:
3,705,346,855,594,120,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 bytes.

Witch is in terabytes: 3,705,346,855,594,120,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 terabytes

Reference: [Is there a (theoretical) limit for amount of data that a contract can store?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/is-there-a-theoretical-limit-for-amount-of-data-that-a-contract-can-store/1040#1040)

> There are 2^256 different keys, and each key can store 32 bytes, so
>   that's a total of 2^261 bytes that could be stored. That said, by then
>   the Ethereum blockchain will probably break due to a hash collision

However, as @eth♦ suggest, you should also consider the gas cost and the block gas limits.

Moreover, if you are using a mapping, a collision may happen because the location of a value key is computed using the hash function `sha3(key, p)`. Check here for more details: [Is there a maximum number of entries for a mapping?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-entries-for-a-mapping). But again this collision is a concern when your data size is about 2^160 or 2^80 bytes. And this is a very large storage to consider.

Comment: 2^261 Bytes is  ≈  3,7*10^78 Bytes, but the estimation for the total data volume stored on earth in year 2025 according to [this article on *forbes.com*](https://www.forbes.com/sites/tomcoughlin/2018/11/27/175-zettabytes-by-2025/#3513adfb5459) is "just" 175 Zettabytes = 1,75*10^23.