# Contract size limit after creation?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, accounts

For example, lets consider the basic example of issuing a token:

```
...string public symbol; 
uint8 public decimals; 
uint256 public totalSupply; 
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf; 
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance; ...
```

Here we are storing in an array the balance for every account. So every time we register a new address, the size of the array increases. As far as I understood the maximun size of data on time creation is limited by the possible Gas quantity to be used. Currently 3M of Gas (around 89KB) per block.

This limitation is only when creating a new transaction? Once the contract is on a transaction, Can it still be growing and growing by receiving new data from other transactions without a limit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a (theoretical) limit for amount of data that a contract can store?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/is-there-a-theoretical-limit-for-amount-of-data-that-a-contract-can-store)

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed no practical size limit. Each time a contract writes to its storage, it uses some gas *at the time*. Nonetheless, this may be spread out over any number of transactions.