# Smart contract's storage

Tags: contract-deployment, dapp-development, storage

I would be grateful if anyone can help me understand the storage of a smart contract. Before someone mention the question as duplicate i want to clarify that i had read the post [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/is-there-a-theoretical-limit-for-amount-of-data-that-a-contract-can-store) but i was confused. Moreover i read the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=storage#accounts) that states:"Every account has a persistent key-value store mapping 256-bit words to 256-bit words called storage." So can i imagine the storage as an array with two columns and 256 rows, where each cell holds 256bits?

The reason i am asking is because i want to use the smart contract as a storage of hash values. So i want each time to store a new hash but i need to know how many 256hash values can be stored.

Comment: The answer of your question is on the first post you linked. There are 2^256 different keys that can be stored, each one of 32 bytes (256 bit).

Comment: I was confused because i thought the answers given about the storage in the post were not the same as the one in the solidity docs. Now i get it, there are 2^256 free spots that each can store 256bits. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my blog post [Understanding Smart Contract Storage](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/) will help.

As to how many hashes you could store:

> There are 2<sup>256</sup> locations to choose from in storage, which is approximately the number of atoms in the known, observable universe.