# Ethereum metadata limit

Tags: security, storage

Couple of days ago Vitalik Buterin tweeted that Ethereum has no metadata limit.

Is that true? Two major questions that bothers me, as a developer:

1. I can store any amount of data inside contacts?
2. If so, does it mean that eth network can be abused, spammed and bumped to huge sizes for individual peer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can store any amount of data in a contract, but no it cannot be easily abused.

While it is true that there is practically no limit to the amount of data you could store, storage on Ethereum is expensive, and carrying out any significant spam or DoS attack would be incredibly cost prohibitive.

See

[What is the cost to store 1KB, 10KB, 100KB worth of data into the ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/872/131)

[Can a contract's internal storage keep increasing forever?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/986/131)

Answer (score 1):

In a web2 setting, when storing data, you have to consider your storage capacity(SDD or HDD) as well as the computational ability(processor power) of your system. DDOS attack occur in a centralized network because storage is cheap. However, in a web3 setting like ethereum network, storage is expensive while computation also require large amount of power(processor power), therefore an attacker will have to spend more to stage an attack.