# Is there a maximum array size in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays

And if so, what is it?

Also, would it differ by *dynamic* and *static* arrays?

My initial guess is that:

- a statically-declared array has a maximum number of slots equal to the largest `uint`, as in `array[max_uint256]`.
- a dynamically-declared array has no "practical" limit to its size (but perhaps a huge theoretical one: see link at bottom)

#### Possibly related

- [Is there a maximum number of entries for a mapping?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-entries-for-a-mapping)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no limits in specification, so arrays may grow up to 2^256-1 elements.

Comment: It’s worth noting that even if such a large array could exist, traversing it would fail due to was constraints.

Comment: @pabloruiz55, as in due to `gas` constraints ?

Comment: Yes, I meant GAS constraints

Comment: Wrong, see here: "Starting from Solidity version 0.6.5 the maximum allocation size for dynamic memory arrays is `2**64-1`" https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/04/06/memory-creation-overflow-bug -- however, oddly `array.length` returns a `uint256`.

Comment: @LukeHutchison yes but only for "dynamic memory" right ?
not in contract storage ?

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k correct, I found out since posting the above comment that storage arrays do not have this limit. https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13071

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k I wrote this up in detail in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a smaller limit on the number of elements that can be in a *dynamic memory array* than the number of elements that can be in a *dynamic storage array* or a *non-dynamic storage array*.

https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/04/06/memory-creation-overflow-bug :

> Starting from Solidity version 0.6.5 the maximum allocation size for dynamic memory arrays is `2**64-1`. Attempting to allocate larger arrays now directly reverts.

However this is specifically for dynamic arrays that are *allocated in memory* (not storage), as a local variable in a function, of the form

```
contract A {
    function x() {
        uint256[] myArray = new uint256[](someLargeNumber);
    }
}
```

Storage arrays are actually just a hashmap (implemented internally using a trie), also with a `length` field that sets the upper bound for indices, and they can store up to `2**256-1` elements (given an Ethereum node the size of the universe...).

Storage arrays can be dynamic too:

```
contract B {
    uint256 dynamicStorageArray[];
    uint256 nonDynamicStorageArray[3];
}
```

But neither of these *storage* array forms has the limit of `2**64-1` elements, both can hold `2**256-1` elements.

Another notable difference: dynamic storage arrays support `push()` and `pop()`. Dynamic memory arrays do not support this.

Internally, both memory arrays and storage arrays store the length of the array in their first memory location, as a `uint256` (so the limit on the number of elements in a dynamic memory array is imposed by compiler-generated logic, not by the inability to represent or store more than this number of elements). `array.length` [always returns a `uint256`](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13071), no matter the type of array or where it is stored out of memory or storage.