# Realistically how big an array inside Ethereum smart contract can be?

Tags: solidity, ether

Does it have to fit in a single block?

Comment: Related (same question - unanswered): [Is there a maximum array size in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/is-there-a-maximum-array-size-in-solidity)

Answer (score 2):

Pushing into it or groupings of computation and storage do have to fit in a single block. For instance, looping the entirety of an array that has a million members will run out of gas in a block.  The number of loops that can be done is also dependent on the computation occurring in each loop too.  If you have a few lines of code in each loop that burn a lot of gas, then you will be able to loop fewer times before reaching the `block gas limit`.

But the total size can be `2^256` 32 byte words which you will never have or be able to afford.