# A smart contract's storage problem , further ERC ？

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, storage

Er .. I have a question about smart contract , a single smart contract's storage capacity

Follow the answer is this question：

**[Is there a (theoretical) limit for amount of data that a contract can store?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1040/16)**

**[Can a contract's internal storage keep increasing forever?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/986/can-a-contracts-internal-storage-keep-increasing-forever)**

In conclusion , A single smart contract only can storage 1.46GB

---

1. If , the limit is 1.46G：

   My question is , will a smart contract storage be full of data , then can't work？

   so , how ERC token storages large number of users and make function still work？

   Is 1.46GB really enough for storaging many users and doing other operation？

---

2. If , a single smart contract has no limit ：

   there is no limit problem , but gas is problem for operation.

   If I actually do precise operation (like: query) to my data , I can keep my data growing whatever , and my function won't happend out of service situation.

   Also , Is this a reason that why ERC token can be afford large number of users？ But how did they make it (not exceed gas)？

---

I'm silly on base problem on smart contract , If any can tell or tag resource(associated knowledge) , really appreciate..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not true that the limit is 1.46GB. A smart contract can theoretically store 2^256 words of 32 bytes. That is a ridiculously huge amount of data.
2. The amount of data used by a smart contract that implements a token (ERC20) is really small. The amount of storage needed to register tokens of 200 Million users is 200 Million words of 32 bytes, which is nothing compared to the theoretical limit of 2^256.

The amount of gas per transaction should be the same independent of how many users are registered in the smart contract.

Hope this helps

Comment: OKay!!  It's very clear and power anwser ... Thank you >< !!!