# geth --exec generates: error: TypeError: Cannot access member 'input' of null

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx

I'm trying to run this command from this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/448/105), however when I run:

```
$ geth --exec "eth.getTransaction('0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117c8dcdac').input" console
```

it gives me the error:

> error: TypeError: Cannot access member 'input' of null

Here is full log:

```
$ geth --exec "eth.getTransaction('0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117c8dcdac').input" console
I0505 18:56:53.049949   26203 flags.go:425] WARNING: No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
I0505 18:56:53.050144   26203 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to ~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
I0505 18:56:53.060683   26203 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to ~/Library/Ethereum/dapp
I0505 18:56:53.067958   26203 backend.go:314] Protocol Versions: [63 62 61], Network Id: 1
I0505 18:56:53.068571   26203 backend.go:362] Blockchain DB Version: 3
I0505 18:56:53.069163   26203 blockchain.go:214] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0505 18:56:53.069181   26203 blockchain.go:215] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0505 18:56:53.069187   26203 blockchain.go:216] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0505 18:56:53.075383   26203 cmd.go:115] Starting Geth/v1.3.6-9e323d65/darwin/go1.6
I0505 18:56:53.075487   26203 server.go:311] Starting Server
I0505 18:56:55.162538   26203 udp.go:212] Listening, enode://bfcb192b0d374ff7c5186a6ee96aa38cd71d8f87afa1e1fa153d42ff0d15ea93f67f035d984af921d21305cb0cd94ee3b71bfab60fc2c4bf5578620d488e4fa0@[::]:30303
I0505 18:56:55.162758   26203 backend.go:526] Server started
I0505 18:56:55.162787   26203 server.go:552] Listening on [::]:30303
I0505 18:56:55.163135   26203 ipc.go:112] IPC service started (~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc)
error: TypeError: Cannot access member 'input' of null
I0506 00:54:47.997968   54842 blockchain.go:690] Chain manager stopped
I0506 00:54:47.997994   54842 handler.go:192] Stopping ethereum protocol handler...
I0506 00:54:47.998007   54842 handler.go:202] Ethereum protocol handler stopped
I0506 00:54:47.998015   54842 tx_pool.go:156] Transaction pool stopped
I0506 00:54:47.998023   54842 backend.go:630] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG OFF (ethash dir: ~/.ethash)
I0506 00:54:47.998163   54842 database.go:158] closed db: ~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
I0506 00:54:47.998488   54842 database.go:158] closed db: ~/Library/Ethereum/dapp
```

And when getting the transaction directly in `geth console` (as suggested), it's printing `null`, e.g.

```
> eth.getTransaction('0x6aae61d3b11e84caf573bb71ae44b9099db8dde996fb29c8b3aa6872681aa87d')
null
```

My `geth` is v1.3.6.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: OP is executing the instruction from [Is there anything stopping me from using the ethereum blockchain as data storage?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-there-anything-stopping-me-from-using-the-ethereum-blockchain-as-data-storage/448#448).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your transaction is not listing is because there are some strange hidden characters in the text you copied and pasted.

The following statement works:

```
eth.getTransaction('0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117c8dcdac')
```

The following statement does not work:

```
eth.getTransaction('0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117‌​c8dcdac')
```

I copied both statements into a text file and used `vi` to view the contents and the strange characters then show up:

[image]

Comment: @kenorb, could you try running `geth console`, then `eth.getTransaction('0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117c8dcdac')`. What do you see?

Comment: You may have found something strange. If you replace your quote characters, it might just work. Try this statement: $ geth --exec 'eth.getTransaction("0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117c8dcdac")' console

Comment: Executing `eth.getTransaction('0x6aae61d3b11e84caf573bb71ae44b9099db8dde996fb29c8b3aa6872681aa87d')` gives `null` even after block synchronisation started.

Comment: Both with single and double-quote when ran multiple times gives `null` (every time). When synchronisation is started, it's quiet difficult to see what I'm executing, because the text about importing blocks is all over the screen.

Comment: Solved the issue. There are some hidden characters in your original text. See the screenshot.

Comment: I've seen it about this too, but then I played a bit with removing them and it resulted in the same thing. I'll check it again.

Comment: Yes, `eth.getTransaction('0xbb8ee9866ee67277986b6f40775469c7a674810ce99dce3caff0d1117c8dcdac')` works fine. I've seen these hidden characters, but removing them before didn't help. Now I've copy & pasted your example, it worked fine!

Comment: No idea how they got there, great catch, thanks. Mostly I was just copy & pasting, maybe some terminal glitch.