# is it possible to run pending transactions on local node to see the outcome?

Tags: mining, parity, pending-transactions, ethminer

I am looking for a way to execute current pending transactions on local node, to see their outcome and log events, without really mine it.

it is some kind of pre-simulation, to see what is going to happen on the next block in the network.

is it possible? how can it be done?

Comment: you can use a private network or a remix IDE's JavaScript VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can totally simulated the transaction througth eth_call.

Her are the code snippets of eth_call and apply transaction (source from [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)):

eth_call (could not change state)

```
// Setup the gas pool (also for unmetered requests)
// and apply the message.
gp := new(core.GasPool).AddGas(math.MaxUint64)
res, gas, failed, err := core.ApplyMessage(evm, msg, gp)
if err := vmError(); err != nil {
    return nil, 0, false, err
}
return res, gas, failed, err
```

apply transaction (could update state)

```
_, gas, failed, err := ApplyMessage(vmenv, msg, gp)
if err != nil {
    return nil, 0, err
}
// Update the state with pending changes
var root []byte
if config.IsByzantium(header.Number) {
    statedb.Finalise(true)
} else {
    root = statedb.IntermediateRoot(config.IsEIP158(header.Number)).Bytes()
}
```

Remember to return the result of simulation when you use `eth_call`.

The solidity function looks like:

```
function simulation() pure public returns(bool result) {
    result = doSimulation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! thats help, is there a way to access the event logs that happens during the transaction call?

Comment: The event was written to receipt when transaction was included. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_processor.go#L122

Answer (score 2):

> The JSON_RPC [eth_call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) method allows you to simulate a transaction on
>   the blockchain, including contract executions.

From :  [How can I execute code locally at given address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/how-can-i-execute-code-locally-at-given-address)

Comment: Thanks! thats help, is there a way to access the event logs that happens during the transaction call?