# How to know from Solidity contract that a transaction is being simulated?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Is there a way to know from a Solidity contract that the current transaction is being simulated and is not going to be included in the blockchain? When I mention "from the contract" I mean from the contract of the token that is being exchanged.

I'm mostly referring to Uniswap token swap transactions.

I mean this type of simulation:

[is it possible to run pending transactions on local node to see the outcome?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69348/is-it-possible-to-run-pending-transactions-on-local-node-to-see-the-outcome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any property a contract could consult to know if it's live or a simulation. I also don't know of a reason for wanting to.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: I have proof that there are people who are doing that. Yes, it is possible, but I do not know how they do it.

Comment: I'm curious. Send it.